# Node Export being downloaded as a .sh file and unable to be imported

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

In my Drupal 7 project, I have some content of a custom content-type (page) that I need to import into another environment.

When I go to this content instance, I select on `Node Export`, which then gives me the option to download the file. When I download the file, it is downloaded as `-.sh`. In my other environment where I want to import this content using a `Node Export Import`, it says that that file isn't allowed..

How is it possible that you aren't able to use a `Node Export` for a `Node Export Import`??? That makes absolutely zero sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can Import and export the content by using "Node Export with Features".

need to enable this module under node export module.

next, you have to go this URL admin/structure/features/create
and create the feature with the particular content type of content and download the module. next, this module you have to enable in another site.
content will be created.but make sure content type of fields same in two sites.